# How to alert input value from JSON (javascript)

Tags: javascript, json

I have a problem trying to alert input values from json object. I get 'undefined' when i execute this code. Can someone please give me some ideas, I think I tried everything.
btw. I have to use JSON because it is my school project.
Thank you! xx

```
<script>
let arr = [];

function adduser(){
    let user = {
        name: document.getElementById("first_name").value,
        lname: document.getElementById("last_name").value,
        text: document.getElementById("txtara").value,
        email: document.getElementById("emails").value
    }

    arr.push(user);
    let json_str = JSON.stringify(arr);
    alert(json_str.name);
}
</script>
```

Comment: `json_str` is a string, not an object. You need to just use `alert(user.name)`.

Comment: maybe you want alert(user.name) of the newly added user

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the rules of the project. The solution given certainly gets you the correct result, but you said you have to use JSON in the project, which the solution doesn't do because it's unnecessary. Perhaps you need to parse the JSON back to an object to meet the project requirements.

Comment: @bearfriend it just says to use "object, JSON", so i guess i can use it however i want

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to "print" a value from string, that's not possible. If you want to convert your array to JSON and next "print" it on an alert, please try this:

```
let user={
name:document.getElementById("first_name").value,
 lname:document.getElementById("last_name").value,
 text:document.getElementById("txtara").value,
 email:document.getElementById("emails").value
}
let json = JSON.parse(user);
alert(json.name);
```

Comment: isn't the variable json in your example a string too? You stringify it.
Even if you stringify just the user, it's not longer an object so I don't see how you can access it's name.

Comment: Yeah, was a copy/paste mistake. Fixed! Thanks!

Comment: Dw, btw now you are parsing an object, don't you need to stringify it first before you can parse?
Still not sure what is the point since the OP is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access json the same way you access an object.
JSON is a string, you can still find user and it's name by searching through a string, but since it's your school project I honestly doubt that is the point of the lesson.

You probably have to to `JSON.parse(arr)[0].name` where 0 is first index of your array, since you push the user to it.